# Derive the marginal distribution of a gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \in {\bf R}^n$ be a gaussian random vector with $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, $\Sigma = QDQ^T$ the eigenvalue decomposition of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, where $D = diag(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. If $Y \sim N(0_{{\bf R}^n}, D)$, then $Z = QY + \mu$ is a copy of $X$ since
\begin{align*}
        {\bf P}(X \in S) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}(\det{\Sigma})^{1/2}} \int_S e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}\ dx
        \\
        &\stackrel{y = Q^T(x-\mu)}{=}  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}(\det{D})^{1/2}} \int_{Q^T(S-\mu)} e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^TD^{-1}y}\ dy.
        \\
        &= {\bf P}(Y \in Q^T(S-\mu)) = {\bf P}(QY+\mu \in S).
    \end{align*}
It seems then the marginal distribution of each component $X_i$ is:
\begin{align*}
        {\bf P}(X_i \in S_i) &= {\bf P}(X \in {\bf R} \times \dots \times S_i \times \dots \times {\bf R}) = {\bf P}(Z \in {\bf R} \times \dots \times S_i \times \dots \times {\bf R})
\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\lambda_i}}\int_{S_i} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(z_i-\mu_i)^2}{\lambda_i})\ dz_i,
\end{align*}
Yet we should expect the variance to be $\Sigma_{ii}$ rather than $\lambda_i$. Is there a mistake in the derivation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the assumption that $QY$ has the same distribution as $Y$. This doesn't hold unless $Y$ is **isotropic**, i.e., the covariance matrix $D$ of $Y$ is proportional to the identity.

If $D$ is proportional to the identity, then indeed $\lambda_i=\Sigma_{ii}$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that now, rotation invariance holds for standard gaussian distribution, and $Y$ is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your last inequality is the one that doesn't hold.
It seems that you have written it for $\Pr(Y \in \dotsc)$, which is different from the probability $\Pr(Z \in \dotsc)$.

You can still use the equality $X \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=} QY + \mu$ by noticing that (for $e_i$ the vector with $1$ in the $i$th entry and $0$s everywhere else)
$$
X_i
= e_i^{\mathrm{T}}X
\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=} e_i^{\mathrm{T}}Q Y + \mu_i,
$$
and hence
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_i)
= e_i^{\mathrm{T}}Q \operatorname{Var}(Y) Q^{\mathrm{T}} e_i
= e_i^{\mathrm{T}} Q D Q^{\mathrm{T}} e_i
= \Sigma_{ii}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.