# Get the marginal density of a gaussian random vector without using linear transformation theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is a subquestion of the original post: [Derive the marginal distribution of a gaussian random vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850784/derive-the-marginal-distribution-of-a-gaussian-random-vector).

Let $X \in {\bf R}^n$ be a gaussian random vector with $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, let $\Sigma = QDQ^T$ be the eigenvalue decomposition of $\Sigma$, where $D = diag(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$. If $Y \sim N(0_{{\bf R}^n}, D)$, then one can show that $Z = QY + \mu$ is a copy of $X$. Now, can we derive the marginal distribution of each component $X_i$, which is univariate normal with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\Sigma_{ii}$, without explicitly using the linear transformation theorem? (the one stating that if $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$, then $Ax+b \sim N(A\mu+b, A \Sigma A^{T}$))

Attempting to Directly compute ${\bf P}(X_i \in S_i) = {\bf P}(QY + \mu \in \pi_i^{-1}(S_i))$ does not seem to simplify the original distribution.

Comment: What is the "linear transformation theorem" that you want to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noted that $X_i$ has the same distribution as $\mu_j + \sum_{j=1}^n q_{ij} Y_j$. The addends are independent [univariate] Gaussian and satisfy $q_{ij} Y_j \sim N(0, q_{ij}^2 \lambda_j)$, so $X_i \sim N\left(\mu_j, \sum_{j=1}^n q_{ij}^2 \lambda_j\right)$. Finally, check that $\sum_{j=1}^n q_{ij}^2 \lambda_j = (QDQ^\top)_{ii} = \Sigma_{ii}$.

Comment: Thank you always for your feedback.